# Format part of cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, formula

How do I format a cell that has the below formula:

`="Should "&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("IF_Present",$C$3)),"Display_This",IF($C$3="","display_that",$C$3))&" be seperated/merged?"`

So it displays like this:

Should **$C$3_Content** be seperated/merged?

Should **Display_This** be seperated/merged?

Should **display_that** be seperated/merged?

Comment: You can't do this with a cell that contains a formula.

Comment: I'm sure I have done it before, but I cannot remember how.

Comment: Probably you first turned it into a string.